# Keep a UIButton fixed on screen when pushing and popping UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

Hi i currently have a navigation based app with a navigation controller, within the app numerous views and pushed and popped back displaying different xibs, what I would like to do is display a button fixed on the screen in the bottom right of the screen, which when tapped will take the user to a help xib,

However at the moment the button is being animated and moved into place every time I push a or pop a view, I would like the button not to move and stay on top of the views when they are being pushed and popped.

Wondering if anyone can help me, thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView Class in that create UIButton And create object of that view in all the viewcontrollers,and add it to the self.view.

Comment: I added the button as a subview of the window in the app delegate and hid and displayed the button accordingly using the alpha property.

Comment: Do one thing create one uiview and add the button on it.Then add the view subclass as window button.The same functionality will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

using this in appdelegate will help u to show button in all the screen.
if u need handle this button, import viewcontrollerAppdelegate.h to the view controller. and use

```
UIAppDelegate.SettingButton.hidden=True;
```

or like this any. just try

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        settingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [settingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingButtonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-lb.png"];
        [settingButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [settingButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        settingButton.frame = CGRectMake(265, 17, 40, 45);
        settingButton.hidden=TRUE;
        [self.window addSubview:settingButton];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }


    - (void)settingButtonPressed:(id) sender {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"settingButtonPressed" object:nil];
        setting *obj = [[setting alloc] initWithNibName:@"setting" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];  
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; 
        [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
        [navController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,480,320,480)];
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:navController.view cache:YES];
        [navController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];    

    }
```